# CDN a bit flaky?

Tags: support

I'm having the occasional problem loading pages on serverfault, and every time I get a "hung" page load, the status bar (or what passes for it in Chromium) will say "Waiting for cdn.sstatic.net".  It's never serverfault.com, or ajax.google-apis.com, or gravatar.com, or any of the other domains that carry some part of the whole page.  It's always the damned CDN.

So, has anyone else noticed a persistent problem with the CDN being the "weak link" in page loads, or do I just have a particularly bad run of luck?

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92452/cdn-sstatic-net-is-slowing-down-initial-page-loads - please go and voice your opinion on there as well!

Comment: P.S. It's not really off topic, but thats the only close reason that came remotely close

Comment: Am I the only one who has noticed that all such problems are posted by people using Chrome?

Comment: An interesting observation, but is there enough data to support that as the likely cause?